# Have Spider-Man and The Flash ever fought?

Tags: marvel, dc, spider-man, the-flash

Have Spider-Man and Flash ever fought against each other?

If so, who won (and how)?

Comment: You might find [this](http://deadliestfiction.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Drayco90/Marvel_vs._DC-_Spider-Man_vs._The_Flash) interesting.

Comment: Well considering one is a Marvel property and the other is a DC property, I am going to assume that you will not see a crossover in the comics or movies. However, with that being said, I am sure that you can find some user created content (fanfic) where the two fought.

Comment: @ToddO'Rourke Marvel and DC have had a few universe-wide crossovers in the past; I don't know if those two in particular have crossed over, though.

Comment: I am going to close this question due to the vs. nature of the question. Such questions tend to be beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Spidey can get airbourne but Flash can't. This might give Spidey the edge... Moreover spider sense will also be a factor. As far as strength is concerned Flash is no match for Spidey. Spidey also has greater intelligence and better ability to make strategies. So I think Spidey might win.

Comment: [Spiderman fought Speed Demon](http://static7.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/0/3853/1205358-speed1.gif). The battle lasted a few seconds, basically as long as it took for him to use his spider-sense to work out where Speed Demon was going to be and stick his arm out.

Comment: Guess what happened when [Spiderman fought Quicksilver](http://static9.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/0/3853/1205399-qs2.jpg). Yup, the battle lasted a few seconds, basically as long as it took for him to use his spider-sense to work out where Quicksilver was going to be and stick his arm out.

Comment: I don't how this is opinon-based. There have been many crossover titles before, and the question isn't "Who do you think would win", but "Did it happen, and if it did, who won?"

Comment: **Please see [this blog post](http://thesffblog.com/2015/06/gorilla-vs-shark-not-so-fast/) for this site's consensus on "vs" questions.** Not all of them are closeworthy.

Answer (score 8):

I can't find or remember any such conflict in licensed media. As mentioned above, there have been crossovers, but these didn't involve direct conflict between these two characters. In [DC vs Marvel Comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_vs._Marvel), The (Wally West with access to The Speed Force) Flash [beat](http://secretearths.blogspot.com/2006/03/flash-versus-quicksilver-showdown-of.html) Quicksilver, (Ben Reilly) Spider-man [beat](http://marvelvsdccomiccrossover.wikia.com/wiki/Spiderman_Vs_Super_Boy) (Kon-El / Connor Kent) Superboy.

Comment: Getting into Shark vs Gorilla territory, A Flash at his/her most powerful would mop up any version of Spider-man without difficulty, though writers could handwave their way to any result that suited them. Less powerful versions of The Flash could plausibly be defeated by more powerful or competent versions of Spider-man, with Spider Sense providing an edge.

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_71

Comment: Spiderman would just perform The Spiderman Maneuver: get horribly beaten for the first two acts, then come up with a clever strategy to defeat his opponent at the last minute.

Comment: How exactly does electrified water kill Superboy? He's either a metahuman or a half-kryptonian. Did they even *read* the comics?

Comment: It wouldn't kill him, but recent Kryptonians have shown a weakness to electrical current, with a sufficiently strong current causing pain and incapacitation.